# wordpress migration: problems with functions

Tags: php, wordpress

I have migrated my wordpress blog to another server and now I find a problem ...

Some functions do not work.

For example the function of showing the thumbnail of each posts or category listing.

No errors, just does not show anything in the html code.

Example:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail ();>
```

Output = ""

Comment: How did you perform the migration to the new server? Did you change the domain of your blog?

Comment: Is there space between "<?" and "php" (also "the_post_thumbnail" and "()") ? If so try to remove it.

Comment: Thanks. the domain is the same, all pictures look good except thumbnails...

Comment: The "space" is my fault, sorry. I will edit...

Answer (score 1):

Use This code

```
if ( have_posts()  ) :  
      $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
      $url = $thumb['0'];
endif;
     <img src="<?php echo $url;?>"/>
```